# Question mark shown instead of theorem number

Tags: cross-referencing

In TexStudios, I labeled and referenced theorems with `\label` and `\ref`. After I compiled the latex document twice, it still shows two question marks instead of my theorem number. My code snippet:

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
    \begin{thm}[Reverse Data Processing Inequality]
        \label{rdpi}
        $ P $ is more informative than Q, i.e. $ P\supseteq Q $ if and only 
        if there exists a Markov matrix $ M $ such that $ Q = PM $. 
    \end{thm} 
In Theorem \ref{rdpi}, we know that...
```

These are my packages:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\KL}{KL}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You are not telling us how thm is defined. Please update your question with a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is instead of sniplets like this where we have to guess

Comment: I hope your `\newtheorem` declaration is *before* `\begin{document}`. Anyway, after two LaTeX runs the number is there.

Comment: I found if I pasted this snippet in a separate document, it worked fine. But when I ran my entire work, question marks showed up. Do other errors in the document interfere with the numbering?

Comment: Look at the first error in your log and begin with solving that one.